# Can I use an existing nullable column as a Discriminator in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, discriminator

I have been searching for a clear answer in the Docs for this but could not find one.

My use case is that I have an existing table using an "unofficial" table-per-hierarchy (TPH) . It is using a column with different values that is later mapped based with the null and not null value in the model.

As part of a refactoring we want to map it correctly in EF but unfortunately we dont have a great amount of freedom as this column is used in the legacy system mapping as well.

My main question is by having a configuration as below I am getting a runtime "Data is null error".

```
       tableBase
            .HasDiscriminator<string>(nameof(tableBase.ExistinColumn))
            .HasValue<Child1>(null)
            .HasValue<Child2>("string1")
            .HasValue<Child2>("string2")
            .HasValue<Child2>("string3");
```

As you can see this column takes 4 values , null should be mapped with the Child1 class and all the rest of them with the Child2 class.

Not sure if thats the way and I have misconfigured this.

Is creating a new column and with a migration script populate it based on the existing column value and finally use it as a discriminator the only way to achieve this ?

This would be of course the best way to do it but I am not sure what kind of issues it will lead in the legacy system.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried nullable reference `HasDiscriminator<string?>(x => x.ExistinColumn)` or setting that discriminator column is not required explicitly `tableBase.Property(x => x.ExistinColumn).IsRequiredFalse()`? Ensure also that `ExistinColumn` is declared as `string?`.

Comment: Creating a new column would probably be the "best" solution if you do want the clean inheritance, and it would just incur the one-off cost. Discriminators are meant to be value-per-class, so even if you were able to solve the #null problem, you'll almost certainly run into issues with mapping multiple values to Child2.

Comment: Thank you guys , Indeed I tried everything but it seems that this is the best possible solution.

Comment: Using NULL as a value is a bad design in databases. NULL means you don't know what the value is. `NULL` isn't even equal to `NULL` in SQL so EF would have to know in advance that the column is nullable and create a different query each time, eg `where that_col='customer'` in one case, `that_col IS NULL` in another.

Comment: NULLs can create serious problems with indexing, depending on the database product. SQL Server includes them in indexes but Oracle *doesn't*. Your query could run fine on one database and crawl to a stop on another. That doesn't mean that one database is right and the others wrong - since NULL is unknown, it's up to the implementation to decide what to do with that unknonw

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned also in the comments , I tried the solution with a new column.
In a POC state of course but it seems to be working fine.

Steps.

1. Created a Discriminator int computed column which takes the values from a scalar function that returns the discriminator value by wrapping the cases.

- 0 when Column Value is null
- 1 when string1
- 2 when string2
- 3 when string3
- -1 when none of them.

2. Created a NotMapped int Discriminator property in TableBase class.

3. EF Mapping modified to below

   ```
       tableBase
            .HasDiscriminator<int>(nameof(tableBase.Discriminator))
            .HasValue<Child1>((int)DeriveTypesEnum.Child1)
            .HasValue<Child2>((int)DeriveTypesEnum.Child2)
            .HasValue<Child3>((intDeriveTypesEnum.Child3)
            .HasValue<Child4> ((int)DeriveTypesEnum.Child4);
   ```